# Rabbitmq giving segmentation fault on M1 mac

Tags: rabbitmq, apple-m1, rabbitmq-exchange

env.conf" /opt/homebrew/opt/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmq-server
/opt/homebrew/opt/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 155:  1332 Segmentation fault: 11  start_rabbitmq_server "$@"

I am getting this error^

I tried reinstalling rabbitmq. I cannot find a solid solution that has worked. I am trying to run it later I will connect it with celery

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: No not yet, If i get I will inform

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the installed version of RabbitMQ is not compatible with arm64 architecture.

The solution is to install arm64-compatible version or to use arm64-compatible docker image of RabbitMQ.

For example, here it's advised using `rabbitmq:3.9.11-management` docker image:
https://github.com/heidiks/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/issues/4#issuecomment-987206858

Answer (score 0):

choose proper image tag which has linux/arm64 OS/arch

Eg: 3.11.10-debian-11-r0 in https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/rabbitmq/tags?page=1